# how to select a subset of columns of a row of a numpy record array?

Tags: python, numpy

I understand the statements like `x[['col1','col2']]` can be used to select columns from a numpy record array.  My question is how to perform the same operation on a single row of a record array.  Here is what I would like to do:

```
Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun  2 2014, 01:41:14)
[...]
IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
[...]

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.ones(3, dtype=[('a',float),('b',float),('c',int)])

In [3]: x[['b','c']][0]
Out[3]: (1.0, 1)

In [4]: row0 = x[0]

In [5]: row0['b']
Out[5]: 1.0

In [6]: row0['c']
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: row0[['b','c']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-287722bfeeaa> in <module>()
----> 1 row0[['b','c']]

IndexError: invalid index
```

I hoped that the last statement gives the result `(1.0, 1)`, but instead I get the error shown above.  How can I extract the specified columns from `row0`?

My real application has many more columns, and which columns I need depends on the row I'm in, so I cannot select the columns before the rows.  Since the equivalent of `row0[['b','c']]` will be executed many times, I would like to avoid using a python loop here.

Part of my problem may be that I don't know the data type of `row0`:

```
In [8]: row0
Out[8]: (1.0, 1.0, 1)

In [9]: row0.dtype
Out[9]: dtype([('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<i8')])
```

`row0` has a `dtype`, so it clearly is not a plain Python tuple.  But it seems not to be a numpy array either:

```
In [10]: type(row0)
Out[10]: numpy.void
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `x[0]` you get a `np.void` object with `ndim=0`. You can do `x[0:1]` instead in order to get a `np.ndarray` object with `ndim=1`, which will accept the column selection:

```
r0 = x[0:1]
r0[['b', 'c']]
#array([(1.0, 1)],
#      dtype=[('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<i4')])
```

You can also transform the `np.void` into a `np.ndarray` in this case doing:

```
r0 = x[0]
r0 = r0.reshape(-1)
```

which will accept the column selection.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find anything in the docs about accessing a record array the way you want - I played around a bit and this seems to work:

```
>>> x = np.ones(3, dtype=[('a',float),('b',float),('c',int)])
>>> r = np.array(x[0])
>>> r
array((1.0, 1.0, 1), 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<i4')])
>>> r[['a','c']]
(1.0, 1)
>>>
```

`r` seems to be a view into `x`:

```
>>> r['a'] = 3
>>> r
array((3.0, 1.0, 1), 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<i4')])
>>> x
array([(3.0, 1.0, 1), (1.0, 1.0, 1), (1.0, 1.0, 1)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<i4')])
```